# CMake to Makefile - Makefile gives `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to familiarize my self with Cmake by following [this](https://www.johnlamp.net/cmake-tutorial-1-getting-started.html#main.cc-1) example:
In short I have this c++ code . I want to generate a makefile for this code using Cmake and then run the makefile. Unfortunately the Makefile generated gives out an error. I am using Windows 7

Here is the code that I am using

**File: main.cpp**

```
#include "ToDo.h"
int main(  int    argc,  char** argv)
{
    ToDo list;

    return 0;
}
```

**File: ToDo.h**

```
#ifndef TODO_H
#define TODO_H

class ToDo
{
public:
    ToDo();
    ~ToDo();
};
```

**File:ToDo.cpp**

```
#include "ToDo.h"


ToDo::ToDo()
{
}

ToDo::~ToDo()
{
}
#endif // TODO_H
```

This my **CMakeLists.txt**

```
project("To Do List")


add_executable(toDo main.cpp ToDo.cpp)
```

Here is what I am doing in cygwin

```
admin@US01WKS03044 /cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - failed
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/CmakeTest/build

admin@US01WKS03044 /cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build
$ ls
cmake_install.cmake  CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  Makefile

admin@US01WKS03044 /cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build
$ make VERBOSE=1
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -HC:/CmakeTest -BC:/CmakeTest/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build'
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" C:/CmakeTest C:/CmakeTest C:/CmakeTest/build C:/CmakeTest/build C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target toDo
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build'
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/main.cpp.o
C:/cygwin64/bin/c++.exe     -o CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/main.cpp.o -c C:/CmakeTest/main.cpp
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:/CmakeTest/build/CMakeFiles 2
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/ToDo.cpp.o
C:/cygwin64/bin/c++.exe     -o CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/ToDo.cpp.o -c C:/CmakeTest/ToDo.cpp
Linking CXX executable toDo.exe
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/objects.a
C:/cygwin64/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/objects1.rsp
C:/cygwin64/bin/c++.exe     -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o toDo.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtoDo.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.33-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.33-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39:(.text.startup+0x7e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [toDo.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/toDo.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/CmakeTest/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why did the Makefile fail ?

Comment: Shouldn't you post some kind of cmakelists.txt file?

Comment: Yeah forgot about that. Posted it - While you were commenting

Comment: Dont know why the downvote

Comment: The error is `/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.33-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain'`. Why that happened I don't know. Are you failing to link against some Windows library? Are you failing to provide some standard Windows entry point (namely `WinMain`)?

Comment: First: Do you need that *#endif // TODO_H* at the end of ToDo.cpp? Second: I'm using linux here and everything compiles fine, in windows you might need to add extra params to the compiler (see mingw about them), and add_executable extra param like "WIN32" (see docs about it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the compiler is looking for `WinMain` as the entrypoint of your executable, instead of the classic `main`, and it can't find it.

As I don't use cygwin, can't really say why that is (WinMain is specific to windows gui apps, if I'm not mistaking), but you could to rename `main` to `WinMain` and see if it works. Or see http://log4aj.blogspot.ro/2010/11/cygwin-gcc-undefined-reference-to.html.

Comment: It gives the same behaviour when running from a cmd in windows